# Touchpad problems after applying updates Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, alps

I have recently started making the move away from Windows to Ubuntu. I have a Dell XPS M1530 onto which I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 as a clean install onto an unpartitioned drive. I allowed Ububtu to set up its own partitions and the install went smoothly. My ALPS 2 touchpad performed perfectly, and in the mouse settings screen was a slide control for touchpad pointer speed and a couple of other check boxes relating to the touchpad. I have now installed the OS updates and the touchpad pointer moves very slowly. The left and right buttons work fine. The mouse settings screen no longer contains any tools relating to the touchpad. Both a wired usb mouse and a wireless usb mouse work fine. I have searched here and elsewhere on the net and tried a few fixes with no success. Any help much appreciated. You have probably gathered I am not a programmer or developer of any kind so please keep it simple.

Thanks in advance for your help

Kurt

PS if you want me to post any screen shots please advise how I can do this too

Thanks

Comment: Hello again, I have been doing some more reading and I have fixed my problem, but I don't know how this works or how to make it permanent. This is what I did...   I changed the value at xinput set-prop 12 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" from 1 to 0.27. The mouse pointer now moves at the proper speed across the screen and it has not affected the operation  of the buttons. How do i make this a permanent change.  Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

run : `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

I'm having the same problem , My laptop is thinkpad T series , with ubuntu 16.04 just upgrade from 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

To make your change permanent, simply add the command you ran in the terminal to `~/.xprofile`.  In the terminal type:

```
nano .xprofile
```

...and add the line(s) of code you had to type into the terminal to get your trackpad working how you wanted.  Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, press Enter to confirm the file name, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

On restart, your configuration should be saved.

Comment: That's it!! Thanks so much!!! If I wanted to edit the line of code that I saved to adjust the pointer speed, do I just do the same again to over write it, or is there an editing process?  Thanks again, Kurt........OK figured that bit out for myself!!